# Task “default” not found in Gruntfile.js

Tags: gruntjs

I'm spending way too much time finding my error. I bet I'm missing a semicolon.

```
module.exports = function  (grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

cssbeautifier : {
files : ["css/style.css"],
options : {
indent: '  ',
openbrace: 'end-of-line',
autosemicolon: false
  }
}
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-cssbeautifier');
grunt.registerTask('default',["cssbeautifier"]);
   })
}
```

package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "zavrsni-php",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Job interview simulator\r Demo: http://interviewsimulator.eu.pn/",
  "main": "index.php",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/MarkoIvanetic/zavrsni-PHP.git"
  },
  "author": "Grad",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/MarkoIvanetic/zavrsni-PHP/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/MarkoIvanetic/zavrsni-PHP#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-cssbeautifier": "^0.1.2",
    "grunt-jsbeautifier": "^0.2.10"
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fount it, braces on the wrong place